# rebuilding tree from file

Tags: c++

I have problem in connecting nodes for my tree. In my program the function `read()` will be executed first then the `load()` function. In `read()` function all data from my external file will be stored in array then rebuild in `load()` function. Variables `dat` and `i` was declared globally. My problem is on the `load()` function. your help is really appreciated.By the way my data on the external file was arranged pre-orderly and I used "#" for NULL nodes.

```
void read()
{
    string dat1;
    fstream file;
    file.open("data.txt", ios::in);
    do
    {
       getline(file,dat1);
       dat[i]=dat1;
       i++;
    }while(!file.eof());
    file.close();
}

void load(node *root,int index)
{

    node *nNode;
    nNode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nNode->yes=NULL;
    nNode->no=NULL;

    nNode->data=dat[index];

    if(index<i)
    {
        if(nNode->data!="#")
        {
            root=nNode;
            load(root->yes,index+1);
            load(root->no,index+1);
        }
        else
        {
            root=NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean; "my problem is on the load function" is it bugged? if so how; does it compile? if not with what error.

Comment: it compiles but nodes are not connected. sorry for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one problem is that you've never actually increased `index` in `load()`. Another problem is that you never assign root->yes or root->no to anything, either. Instead, you assign the pass-by-value parameter `root`. Perhaps you wanted this to be by reference as well.

You likely want something more like:

```
// note that root and index are now pass-by-reference
void load(node &*root,int &index)
{
    ...
        index++;
        load(root->yes,index);
        index++;
        load(root->no,index);
    ...
}
```